# Suggestions: Anti-Pattern counter-examples

Tags: design-patterns, anti-patterns

It doesn't seem that this exact question has been asked before, so I'll fire away:

Most of us are familiar with the concept of an anti-pattern. However, avoiding implementation of anti-patterns can in principle swing too far the other way and cause problems itself. As an example, "Design by Committee" has a counter-example that I'd call "Design by Maverick" - wherein the design of an important feature is handed off to an individual to do what they think best, with the intention of reviewing their work later and deciding whether it should be finalised or go through another iteration. This takes much longer in practice as the rest of the team are occupied by other things, and can end up with a feature that's useful to nobody, particularly if the Maverick is not themselves an experienced end-user.

Does anyone have any more examples of anti-pattern counter-examples?

Comment: This is an odd use of the word "counter-example". Intuitively, I would have thought a counter-example was the use of a so-called anti-pattern that actually leads to good results.

Comment: That's a fair point. The line of reasoning in my head was that an anti-pattern is "Don't do x" but conversely, a counter-example means "But also don't do y in order to avoid x"

Comment: I think that your "Design by Maverick" is simply another anti-pattern. It isn't the direct opposite or counter-example of "Design by Committee".

Comment: I suppose that's why my decision to call it an example - it's an anti-pattern that can readily come about from overzealously avoiding the first anti-pattern. It doesn't mean that it's exclusive to that behaviour, by any means. I'd intended the discussion to highlight these problems - particularly if the likely result is one that doesn't have a familiar "anti-pattern name"

Comment: This should be a community wiki, as there is no single answer to your question.

Comment: I thought somebody might say that, but I don't know what a community wiki is. I know what a wiki is, obviously. Is it polite euphemism for 'go and bother somebody else'?

Comment: No, it is a feature in SO. Lots of questions are marked "community wiki" because there is no single answer, no "right" and "wrong" (opinion/perspective/personal/subjective questions). Edit your post, and you'll find a "community wiki" checkbox.

Comment: "Design by Maverick"  -- Ooh, I think I am very guilty of this...

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem in anti-patterns themselves. It is easy to point out wrong solutions, but it is harder to come up with good ones. Almost always the quality of solution depends on the context, so sometime even anti-pattern when implemented good can be used more than other solutions. So the space for solutions or patterns in general is quite inexhaustable and we have to decide which ones should be looked at. Wrong solutions or good soltions? I guess looking at bad solutions and knowing that they are bad is not as useful as looking at the good ones, because out of good ones (regular patterns) you can get also good principles which were used when comming up with that solution (as with OO design principles in GoF design patterns book). As to your exact example, I heard somewhere about "Benevolent Dictator" and some sort of democracy (with own name) which was adjusted by adding more votes to certain people depending on different priorities of the project.